# Column name containing a space in Plots.jl

Tags: csv, dataframe, julia, plots.jl

I am trying to plot a specific column of a data frame with a name containing a space in Julia Plots.jl (GR backend).

Here is my data frame structure:

```
17-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 Symbol("DATE/TIME")      
 [...]                
 :TEMPERATURE             
 Symbol("EXT TEMPERATURE")
 :PIM                     
 [...]
```

Here's my code:

```
using CSV, DataFrames
me=CSV.File(joinpath(dir,"myfile.csv"),delim=';')
medf=me|>DataFrame
using Plots,StatPlots,GR
@df medf GR.plot(Symbol("EXT TEMPERATURE"),title="Temperature")
```

This fails with:

```
MethodError: no method matching plot(::Symbol)
Closest candidates are:
  plot(!Matched::Union{AbstractString, Function, AbstractArray{T,2} where T, AbstractArray{T,1} where T}...; kv...) at C:\Users\condo\.julia\packages\GR\joQgG\src\jlgr.jl:1118
```

I can:

```
@df medf GR.plot(:TEMPERATURE)
```

But I can't:

```
@df medf GR.plot(:EXT TEMPERATURE)
```

How should I go about referencing this column in this particular situation?

Comment: Can you rename the column with names! or do you need the column name to keep that space?

Comment: I'd prefer to keep the original column name.

Comment: Your question is precisely why the R version of DataFrame has the check.names-TRUE option, which automatically changes the column label to be a valid name.

Comment: CSV.File has a normalizenames option for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macro `@df` in [`StatPlots`](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/StatPlots.jl) seems to have a few limitations.  Fortunately, the `StatPlots` package provides `cols()` as a workaround for your situation.

Try:

```julia
using CSV, DataFrames
me=CSV.File(joinpath(dir,"myfile.csv"),delim=';')
medf=me|>DataFrame
using StatPlots
gr()  # N.B.: You can include things like size=(400,300), or dpi=400 here as params
@df medf plot(cols(Symbol("EXT TEMPERATURE")),title="Temperature")
```

Answer (score 2):

I've just hit this issue while importing an SPSS file with a `.sav` extension. One may also reference the symbol with a space in the name by doing the following:

```
Symbol("SOME NAME WITH SPACE")
```

I noticed you had done that in some code of yours but not everywhere you use the name with spaces. You should be able to do that in subsequent calls too. For example you could have:

```
@df medf GR.plot(Symbol("EXT TEMPERATURE"))
```

In my case I have a lot of columns in my SPSS file with spaces in the name so I wrote a macro to do this for me:

```
macro s_str(s)
  Expr(:quote, Symbol(s))
end
```

Then subsequent calls can be done like this:

```
@df medf GR.plot(s"EXT TEMPERATURE")
```

I'm using this with good results on DataFrames, YMMV on other packages.

Answer (score 1):

Julia has a tendency to treat the Symbol constant :symb as if it were a variable name in some contexts, and so it becomes awkward if you try to use Symbols containing spaces as if they are variable names, since variable names in Julia cannot contain spaces.

You can however also refer to the DataFrame column by its position this way:

```
using CSV, DataFrames, Plots
iob = IOBuffer("""DATE/TIME,EXT TEMPERATURE\n2018-10-10 12:30, 22.4\n2018-10-11 08:10,26.1\n""")
df = convert(DataFrame, CSV.read(iob))
plot(df[2], ylabel=names(df)[2])
```

Comment: Good, but I'd prefer to refer to the column by name, since I'm familiar with the structure of the CSV file.